# Difference between hash functions and algorithms?

Tags: hash, terminology

Wikipedia lists "Hash function algorithms" within the "Hash function" page. I'm wondering what are the differences and if I can use the terms "hash(ing?) algorithm" and "hash function" interchangeably.

Comment: Hash is the function, algorithm is the implementation.

Comment: @DannyNiu That's not true. An algorithm is an abstract concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, an algorithm is a method of computing a function. The function is the thing you stick an input into and get an output from. The algorithm is how it does it. In the context of cryptography, however, *hash function* and *hash algorithm* are often used interchangeably. People will know what you mean by it.

I believe hash function is the more common term though. Plain old *hash* is  totally fine as well.